# How can I align an form right without making centered element's position off?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a webpage, where I have a header(div) with an img and a form inside it.

The img is centered with the center tag, and i align the form to the right with `float: right;`.

The problem is, that **using `float: right;` makes the centering of the img off**.

**How can I align the form element right, without making the centered element's position off?**

Comment: can you add your code

Comment: @kittyCat the code is messed up right now. you can do anything you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flex. The invisible item and form should have same width.

```css
.header{
  height:60px;
  background-color:green;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center;
}
.header>div:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
  width:100px;
}
.header img{
  width:80px;
  height:50px;
  margin:0;
  padding:5px;
}
.header form{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  margin-left:auto;
  width:100px;
}
.header form input{
  width:90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div>invisible</div>
  <img src="http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/b/b8/Nature.jpg/240px-Nature.jpg"/>
  <img src="http://images.financialexpress.com/2015/12/Lead-image.jpg"/>
  <form>
    <input type="text"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want this? Also what about the form, same line of img? Please post your code

```css
form {
  overflow: hidden;
}
input {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}
img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Center an Image and form at right , wanna same line???</h2>
<p>To center an image, use margin: auto; and make it into a block element:</p>

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/0kQMU8i.png" alt="Paris" style="width:40%">
  <form>
  <input name="declared_first" value="above" />
  <input name="declared_second" value="below" />
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't even work in GitHub's code snippet runner.